# dynamic_cast from "void *"

Tags: c++, rtti, void-pointers, dynamic-cast

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155277/cannot-dynamic-cast-void-to-templated-class), `void*` has no RTTI information, therefore casting from `void*` is not legal and it make sense.

If I remember correctly, `dynamic_cast` from `void*` was working on gcc.

Can you please clarify the issue.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`dynamic_cast` works only on polymorphic types, i.e. classes containing virtual functions.

In gcc you can `dynamic_cast` **to** `void*` but not **from**:

```
struct S
{
    virtual ~S() {}
};

int main()
{
    S* p = new S();
    void* v = dynamic_cast<void*>(p);
    S* p1 = dynamic_cast<S*>(v); // gives an error
}
```

Answer (score 24):

In `5.2.7 - Dynamic cast [expr.dynamic.cast]` it says that for `dynamic_cast<T>(v)`:

- If `T` is a pointer type, `v` shall be an rvalue of a pointer to complete class type
- If `T` is a reference type, `v` shall be an lvalue of a complete class type (thanks usta for commenting on my missing this)

...

- Otherwise, `v` shall be a pointer to or an lvalue of a polymorphic type

So, no, a `(void*)` *value* is not allowed.

Let's think about what your request might mean: say you've got a pointer that's really to a `Derived1*`, but the code `dynamic_cast`-ing only knows it's a `void*`.  Let's say you're trying to cast it to a `Derived2*`, where both derived classes have a common base.  Superficially, you might think all the pointers would point to the same `Base` object, which would contain a pointer to the relevant virtual dispatch table and RTTI, so everything could hang together.  But, consider that derived classes may have multiple base classes, and therefore the needed `Base` class sub-object might not be the one to which the `Derived*` - available only as a `void*` - is pointing.  It wouldn't work.  Conclusion: the compiler needs to know these types so it can perform some adjustment to the pointers based on the types involved.

```
Derived1* -----> [AnotherBase]
                 [[VDT]Base]    <-- but, need a pointer to start of
                 [extra members]    this sub-object for dynamic_cast
```

(Some answers talk about the need for the pointer you're casting from to be of a polymorphic type, having virtual functions.  That's all valid, but a bit misleading.  As you can see above, even if the `void*` is to such a type it still wouldn't work reliably without the full type information, as the real problem is that `void*` is presumably pointing to the start of the derived object, whereas you need a pointer to the base class sub-object from which the cast-to type derives.)

Comment: If T is a pointer type, v shall be an rvalue of a pointer to complete class type, ... If T is a reference type, v shall be an lvalue of a complete class type, ...

Answer (score 5):

It is true that `void*` can't be `dynamically_cast`ed from.

You are probably mis-remembering. 
With g++ 4.5 and the following code

```
struct A {
    virtual ~A();
};

int main() {
    A a;
    void *p = &a;
    A* pa = dynamic_cast<A*>(p);
}
```

I get the following error:

> cannot dynamic_cast 'p' (of type 'void*') to type 'struct A*' (source is not a pointer to class)

Answer (score 3):

To add to Tony's nice answer, this little code snippet helps me for some reason.  First, we establish a simple hierarchy.  Then, we see if `dynamic_cast` can "survive" a `static_cast`.  Before this experiment I thought "the run time type information is there, dynamic cast should figure it out."  Now I realize "`dynamic_cast` must have to look up its information based on some tables the compiler is aware of, so it can't have some magical power."

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

class A {
  protected:
  virtual void foo() { cout << "A" << endl; }
};

class B1 : public A {
  private:
  virtual void foo() override { cout << "B1" << endl; }
};

class B2 : public A {
  public:
  virtual void foo() override { cout << "B2" << endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  B1 b1;
  // undefined behavior even though dynamic_cast didn't return null
  dynamic_cast<B2*>(
      static_cast<B2*>(
        static_cast<A*>(&b1)))->foo();
  // dynamic_cast returns null here though
  assert (!dynamic_cast<B2*>
          (static_cast<A*>
           (static_cast<B2*>
            (static_cast<A*>(&b1)))));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you confuse with `dynamic_cast` *to* `void*`. That is legal and obtains the pointer to the most derived class object.

`dynamic_cast` *from* `void*` is illegal - the type casted from must be polymorphic - contain at least one virtual function (virtual destructor counts too).

Comment: Unless the class type casted to is an unambiguous accessible base class of the casted-from expression's class type, in which case the latter need not be polymorphic.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast a pointer to polymorphic type to `void *`, but not vice versa.