# Why i32 Box type can be downcasted in Rust?

Tags: rust

We can use `std::any::Any` to gather different types into a `Box`.

```
use std::any::Any;

fn foo(value: Box<dyn Any>) {
    if let Some(string) = value.downcast_ref::<String>() {
        println!("String: {}", *string);
    } else if let Some(int) = value.downcast_ref::<i32>() {
        println!("i32: {}", *int);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Box::new("hello".to_owned());
    let y = Box::new(123);
    foo(x);
    foo(y);
}
```

we can also use `downcast` to identify the type of a value in a `Box`. I learnt that the types in C++ can be determined by virtual functions, according to this question, [How does RTTI work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805980/how-does-rtti-work). However, types like `i32` can also be downcasted in Rust. How does it work?

Comment: The question is not about C++, thus the tag is removed. BTW RTTI has nothing to do with virtual functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `let y = Box::new(123)` here, `y` is inferred to be `Box<dyn Any>`, **not** `Box<i32>`. This is essentially equivalent to writing `let y = Box::new(123) as Box<dyn Any>`, which might make it more obvious what's happening: you're upcasting the box to add the typeid of `i32` when constructing it so that you can downcast it back later.

Answer (score 4):

> However, types like i32 can also be downcasted in Rust.

As Aplet123 notes, because you're using them as arguments to `foo` your `x` and `y` are inferred and immediately created as `Box<dyn Any>`, not `Box<String>` or `Box<i32>`.

The downcasting feature then comes from `dyn Any`, `Box<dyn Any>` is a "fat pointer", it contains the original data but also a vtable of `Any` for whatever type is erased, which [provides the wapped concrete type's `TypeId`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html#tymethod.type_id). This, then, can be checked against the id of the requested type (the downcasting target), and in case of match we "know" the value is of the correct type, and can then transmute the pointer:

```
    // Get `TypeId` of the type this function is instantiated with.
    let t = TypeId::of::<T>();

    // Get `TypeId` of the type in the trait object (`self`).
    let concrete = self.type_id();

    // Compare both `TypeId`s on equality.
    if t == concrete {
        unsafe { &*(self as *const dyn Any as *const T) }
    } else {
        None
    }
```

Essentially, `dyn Any` provides a limited ad-hoc RTTI, rather than have it as a general language feature like C++.