# How to check if Void pointer can be converted to other specific pointer type?

Tags: c++, pointers, void

I have a method that has a void pointer as argument. In the body of the method I want to write some code that should execute only if the void pointer is convertible to a specific type of pointer(in my case it is a card*). How do I check if the card is convertible to card pointer?

Comment: Do you mean: you want to know if the pointer *actually points to* a `card` object ?  In many cases you can convert a pointer but not then use the pointer after conversion.

Answer (score 1):

There is no C++ language feature to do this.

[Don't do this] One possible approach is to make the `void*` point to a class of a specific known type that stores type information and another `void*`. Then you can convert the first `void*` to the type-containing data type, determine if the type is what you want, and then take the nested `void*` and cast it to the desired type.

All that said, what's the *real* problem you're trying to solve? There's probably a C++-idiomatic approach to *that*.

Comment: Including your own type information may be the only way to do this. If you need the `void*`, then you always have to assume you were given the right data type. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131091/dynamic-cast-from-void

Comment: While it is best to avoid `void*`, sometimes you need to use it to provide a hook. For example, when I write multi-threaded code, `pthread_create` expects a function pointer of type `void *(*func)(void*)`, because it can't know what types I may want to use. (Yes, I use pthreads, the compiler I have to use doesn't support c++11.)

Comment: @KyleA: That's because `pthreads` is C, not even C++98. In C++98, you can have `class Runnable { virtual void run() = 0; virtual ~Runnable();}`.